# Card Game using pygame module

Tags: python, object-oriented, game, pygame

I implemented a card game using pygame, the game is a game of war and using png files that I made in Microsoft paint. I tried to keep the object classes as separated from the pygame module as possible. The idea of this is so I can use the CardClasses module with other graphical interfaces, and to reuse it on different games whose displays will be different. When I go to rewrite this, or something similar the idea is to plan on using a Game class as opposed to the more function paradigm I wrote here. I learned that I cant upload the card image files here so I will upload the code in hopes that some brave soul will comb through the lines and give me some feedback. Looking at how to rewrite the doc strings, I feel as though they are weak and only give the idea of the functions or classes they represent.

CardClasses.py

```
"""Created: 3/30/2019

Objects to represent a playing Card, playing Deck, and Player
"""

from enum import Enum
from itertools import product
from random import shuffle

class ranks(Enum):
    TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE = range(2, 15)

class suits(Enum):
    CLUBS,DIAMONDS,HEARTS,SPADES = range(1, 5)

class Card(object):
    """Card object represents a standard playing card.

    The object attributes, suit and rank, are implemented as enums whose values determine the weight of the card
    """

    def __init__(self, suit, rank, in_deck = False, image = None):
        if rank in ranks and suit in suits:
            self.rank = rank
            self.suit = suit
        else:
            self.rank = None
            self.suit = None

        self.in_deck = in_deck
        self.image = image
        self.position_x, self.position_y = 0,0
        self.horizontal_demension = None
        self.vertical_demension = None

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rank.name) + " " + str(self.suit.name)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True if self.rank == other.rank and self.suit == other.suit else False

    def __gt__(self, other):
        """Tests suit precedence, if suits are equal then checks ranks precedence"""
        if self.suit == other.suit:
            if self.rank.value > other.rank.value:
                return True
        if self.suit.value > other.suit.value:
            return True

        return False

class Deck(object):
    """A deck is a collection of 52 Card objects

    Object attributes: cards, removed
    methods: draw(range = 1), deck_shuffle()
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = [Card(suit, rank, in_deck = True) for suit, rank in product(suits, ranks)]
        self.removed = []

    def __str__(self):
        return str([str(card) for card in self.cards])

    def draw(self, range = 1):
        """Draw card(s) by removing them from deck"""
        drawn_cards = self.cards[:range]
        for card in drawn_cards:
            card.in_deck = False
        del self.cards[:range]
        self.removed.append(drawn_cards)
        return drawn_cards

    def deck_shuffle(self):
        """Shuffles deck object in place"""
        shuffle(self.cards)

class Player(object):
    """Implementation of a player object

    Object attributes: name, hand, score, turn, card_selected
    methods: remove_from_hand(card)
    """

    def __init__(self, name, hand = None, score = 0, turn = False):
        self.name = name
        self.hand = hand
        self.score = score
        self.turn = turn
        self.selected_card = None

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

    def remove_from_hand(self, card):
        """Removes a card object from the players hand"""
        if card and card in self.hand:
            position = self.hand.index(card)
            del self.hand[position]
            return card
        return None
```

Game.py

```
"""3/31/2019

Implementation of game of war using pygame and CardClasses
"""
from CardClasses import *
import pygame
green = (0, 200, 50)

def show_hand(screen, player):
    """Displays all cards in hand of player on pygame display object"""
    x, y, space_between_cards = 5, 462, 5
    for card in player.hand:
        card.position_x, card.position_y = x, y
        screen.blit(card.image, (x, y))
        x += card.horizontal_demension + space_between_cards

def select_card(player, mouse_x, mouse_y):
    """Player selects a card to play"""
    if mouse_x:
        for card in player.hand:
            lower_x, upper_x = (card.position_x, card.position_x + card.horizontal_demension)
            lower_y, upper_y = (card.position_y, card.position_y + card.vertical_demension)

            if mouse_x > lower_x and mouse_x < upper_x:
                if mouse_y > lower_y and mouse_y < upper_y:
                    player.selected_card = card

def load_card_images(player):
    "Loads image, and demensions to card objects"
    for card in player.hand:
        card.image = pygame.image.load("Cards/" + str(card) + ".png")
        width, hieght = card.image.get_size()
        card.horizontal_demension = width
        card.vertical_demension = hieght

def play_selected_card(screen, player):
    """Display card that is selected on pygame display object"""
    x = player.selected_card.position_x = 220
    y = player.selected_card.position_y
    screen.blit(player.selected_card.image, (x,y))

def show_winner(screen, player1, player2, my_font):
    """Display text stating game winner at end of game"""
    screen.fill(green)
    winner = str(player1) if player1.score > player2.score else str(player2)
    textsurface = my_font.render("The winner is: " + winner, False, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(textsurface, (100, 270))

def update_selected_card_position(player, new_y_position):
    """Change the Y position of selected card to move card to played position"""
    if player.selected_card:
        player.selected_card.position_y = new_y_position

def evaluate(player1, player2):
    """determines who won round and updates their score"""
    round_winner = None
    if player1.selected_card and player2.selected_card:
        pygame.time.delay(1000)
        round_winner = player1 if player1.selected_card > player2.selected_card else player2
        round_winner.score += 1
        player1.selected_card, player2.selected_card = None, None
    return round_winner

def show_player_scores(screen, player1, player2):
    """Left corner is player 1 score, right corner is player 2 score"""
    font_size = 12
    my_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', font_size)
    textsurface1 = my_font.render("Player 1 score: " + str(player1.score), False, (0, 0, 0))
    textsurface2 = my_font.render("Player 2 score: " + str(player2.score), False, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(textsurface1, (0,0))
    screen.blit(textsurface2, (470,0))

def flip_turns(player1, player2):
    """Negates Turn attributes of player1 and player2"""
    player1.turn = not player1.turn
    player2.turn = not player2.turn

def turn(player, mouse_x, mouse_y, new_y_position):
    """Player will select card using mouse_x, and mouse_y, card will be removed from hand and played"""
    select_card(player, mouse_x, mouse_y)
    player.remove_from_hand(player.selected_card)
    update_selected_card_position(player, new_y_position)

def winner_goes_first(winner, loser):
    """Sets the winner to the starter of the next round"""
    winner.turn = True
    loser.turn = False

def main():
    """GAME of war, each player is given a hand of 10 cards, on each turn a player will select a card to play,
    players cards will be compared and the player with the greater in value card will be assigned a point for round victory.
    When all cards in hand have been played game ends and winner is displayed

    """

    sc_width, sc_height = 555, 555
    selected_card_y_pos_player_1 = 330
    selected_card_y_pos_player_2 = 230
    font_size = 30
    delay_time_ms = 1000
    number_of_cards = 10
    turn_count = 1

    deck = Deck()
    deck.deck_shuffle()
    player1 = Player(input("Player 1 name: "), hand = deck.draw(number_of_cards), turn = True)
    player2 = Player(input("Player 2 name: "), hand = deck.draw(number_of_cards))

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((sc_width, sc_height))
    load_card_images(player1)
    load_card_images(player2)

    pygame.font.init()
    my_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', font_size)

    """Main Game Loop"""
    game_is_running = True
    while game_is_running:
        screen.fill(green)

        mouse_x, mouse_y = None, None
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_is_running = False
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if player1.turn:
            show_hand(screen, player1)
            turn(player1, mouse_x, mouse_y, selected_card_y_pos_player_1)
            if player1.selected_card:
                flip_turns(player1, player2)
        else:
            show_hand(screen, player2)
            turn(player2, mouse_x, mouse_y, selected_card_y_pos_player_2)
            if player2.selected_card:
                flip_turns(player1, player2)

        if player1.selected_card:
            play_selected_card(screen, player1)
        if player2.selected_card:
            play_selected_card(screen, player2)

        show_player_scores(screen, player1, player2)
        pygame.display.update()

        winner = evaluate(player1,player2)
        if winner:
            if winner == player1:
                winner_goes_first(player1, player2)
            else:
                winner_goes_first(player2, player1)

        if not player1.hand and not player2.hand:
            show_winner(screen, player1, player2, my_font)
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(delay_time_ms)
            game_is_running = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```